# Custom Accessor on Entity Model Spring Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, entity, accessor

I've been coding using Laravel and now I want to learn Spring with Kotlin and my first problem is.. How do I make custom accessor in model like I usually do in Laravel?

In Laravel we do:

```
public function getTypeAttribute($value) {
  return strtoupper($value);
}
```

How do I do this in Spring Kotlin Entity Model? Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

To define [custom accessors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters) on a `property`, you use following syntax

```
class TestClass {
    var name: String = ""
        get(){
            // You can reference the backing field with identifier `field` in accessors
            // print("Current value of field is : $field")
            return getNameFromDb()
        }

        set(value){
            setNameInDB(value)
        }
}

// Now if you do the following

val name = TestClass().name     // This will call the get() block
TestClass().name = "SomeName"   // This will call the set(value) block
```